Knitting R rmd to pdf Error
I am stuck on a problem on knitting R, this is the error code that i got:
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.4.4)  4 APR 2024 22:30
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**CodeJawabanSoalPrak2.tex
(./CodeJawabanSoalPrak2.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen141
)) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen142
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count196
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count197
\leftroot@=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count199
\DOTSCASE@=\count266
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen143
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count267
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count268
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count269
\dspbrk@lvl=\count270
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count271
\column@=\count272
\maxfields@=\count273
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen144
\alignsep@=\dimen145
\tagshift@=\dimen146
\tagwidth@=\dimen147
\totwidth@=\dimen148
\lineht@=\dimen149
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks22
\inpenc@posthook=\toks23
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 274.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks24
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count274
\Gm@cntv=\count275
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count276
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen150
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen151
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen152
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen153
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen154
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen155
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen156
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen157
\Gm@dimlist=\toks25
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Package: fancyvrb 2024/01/20 4.5c verbatim text (tvz,hv)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count277
\FV@InFile=\read2
\FV@TabBox=\box53
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count278
\FV@StepNumber=\count279
\FV@OutFile=\write3
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
\OuterFrameSep=\skip53
\fb@frw=\dimen158
\fb@frh=\dimen159
\FrameRule=\dimen160
\FrameSep=\dimen161
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen162
\Gin@req@width=\dimen163
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bookmark.sty
Package: bookmark 2023-12-10 v1.31 PDF bookmarks (HO)
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hypertext links for LaTeX
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2023-11-26 v2.56 Cross-referencing by name of section
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
))
\c@section@level=\count280
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count281
)
\@linkdim=\dimen164
\Hy@linkcounter=\count282
\Hy@pagecounter=\count283
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count284
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 4062.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4179.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4184.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4187.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4194.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4199.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4446.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count285
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4784.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen165
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count286
\Field@Width=\dimen166
\Fld@charsize=\dimen167
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6063.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6068.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6071.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6078.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6083.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6088.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6093.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count287
\c@Item=\count288
\c@Hfootnote=\count289
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend package
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count290
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count291
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 285.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip54
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bkm-pdftex.def
File: bkm-pdftex.def 2023-12-10 v1.31 bookmark driver for pdfTeX and luaTeX (HO)
\BKM@id=\count292
))
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmr on input line 113.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
) (/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-03-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count293
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box54
)
No file CodeJawabanSoalPrak2.aux.
\openout1 = `CodeJawabanSoalPrak2.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 113.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 485.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+lmr on input line 115.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd
File: ot1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OML+lmm on input line 115.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd
File: omllmm.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMS+lmsy on input line 115.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd
File: omslmsy.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMX+lmex on input line 115.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd
File: omxlmex.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 115.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 115.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 115.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 115.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 115.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmtt on input line 117.
(/Users/kenichi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmtt.fd
File: t1lmtt.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/lmtt/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/lmtt/b/n' tried instead on input line 119.

! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ^^[ (U+001B)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.181 \end{verbatim}
                     
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11366 strings out of 476064
 174926 string characters out of 5791819
 1931493 words of memory out of 5000000
 33332 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 581052 words of font info for 59 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 89i,6n,93p,363b,385s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


Can anyone help?

Welcome to tex.sx.

The error is
 LaTeX Error: Unicode character ^^[ (U+001B)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

U+001B is the ESCAPE control character so the question is why do you have that in the source.file?
Howver adding
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{001B}{[ESCAPE]}

will make that character print as [ESCAPE]  (you could put any text there).
